# How to insert object into list of objects in react?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-state-management, nested-object

I have list of nested objects as:

```
          this.state = {
              
           lst: [
            {
                id: "TKT4321",
                subject: "abc",
                reply: [
                    { id: "TKT34343", subject: "axyz" },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "TKT34341",
                subject: "aaaaa",
                reply: [
                    { id: "TKT322", subject: "abfjf" },
                ]
            },                
        ],            
    }
```

I want to append object to reply property . e.g

```
           {
                id: "TKT34341",
                subject: "aaaaa",
                reply: [
                    { id: "TKT322", subject: "abfjf" },
                    { id: "TK2222", subject: "jkjk" },
                ]
            },
```

Which is the best way to do it ? Please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, here working example:

```js
let lst = [
            {
                id: "TKT4321",
                subject: "abc",
                reply: [
                    { id: "TKT34343", subject: "axyz" },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "TKT34341",
                subject: "aaaaa",
                reply: [
                    { id: "TKT322", subject: "abfjf" },
                ]
            },                
        ];
        
        let result = lst.map(el => {
           if (el.id === "TKT34341"){
               el.reply.push({ id: "TK2222", subject: "jkjk" });
           }
           return el;
        });
        
        console.log(result);
```

Then if you want to store `result` into state, just call `this.setState({lst : result});`

Comment: if the object is like  **{ id: "TKT4321", subject: "abc, }** and if i want to add  **reply: [ { id: "TKT34343", subject: "axyz" }, ]** to it so that it will look like **{ id: "TKT4321", subject:"abc", reply: [ { id: "TKT34343", subject: "axyz" },]  }**  How to do it ? Actually i just started learning react so struggling with nested objects .

Comment: Ciao, you could do something like: `let value = { id: "TKT4321", subject: "abc" }; value.reply =  [ { id: "TKT34343", subject: "axyz" } ];` that's it. With JSON object you can add any elements you want just writing object.newElement = <allThatYouWant>!

Comment: No problem @sau :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the state, you can use the spread operator `...` like this:

```js
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const { lst } = prevState
  return lst.map((elem) => ({
     ...elem,
     reply: [ ...elem.reply, { id: "TK2222", subject: "jkjk" } ]
  }))
})
```

I haven't tried this out, but you can get the idea from this example.